# CI_PROJECT_DIR not respected in gitlab CI rules

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

Consider the following pipeline:

```yaml
image: alpine

stages:
  - test

this-does-not-run:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_DIR == "/builds/test"
  script:
    - echo "It works!"

this-runs:
  stage: test
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PROJECT_DIR != "/builds/test"
  script:
    - echo "It doesn't work! CI_PROJECT_DIR- $CI_PROJECT_DIR"
```

And assume my repo is called `test`.  The output of this CI will always be:

```
It doesn't work!  CI_PROJECT_DIR- /builds/test
```

Obviously `$CI_PROJECT_DIR == /builds/test`, so I would expect the output to be `It works!`.  Am I missing something, or is `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` not respected in `rules`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that variables in `rules:` must be expanded (evaluated by) **the GitLab server at pipeline creation time**, but `$CI_PROJECT_DIR` is determined by the runner's `builds_dir` setting, which is [only known **by the runner at runtime**](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/where_variables_can_be_used.html#gitlab-internal-variable-expansion-mechanism) when the job actually runs:

> References to unavailable variables are left intact. In this case, the runner attempts to expand the variable value at runtime. For example, a variable like CI_BUILDS_DIR is known by the runner only at runtime.

That is to say, like `CI_BUILDS_DIR`, you can't use `CI_PROJECT_DIR` or other runtime-only variables in `rules:if:`. Instead, you should use a variable that is known to the gitlab server at pipeline creation time, such as `CI_PROJECT_NAME` `CI_PROJECT_ID`, `CI_PROJECT_URL`, `CI_PROJECT_PATH_SLUG` or similar.

Answer (score -1):

Try to wrap the expression in quotes. Afaik this is an expression and you would need to wrap it.

Eg:

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR == "/builds/test"'
```

If you only have variables, then from experience you don't need to wrap it.
Eg:

```
rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```