# GitLab pipeline with changes rules never runs automatically

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

I am trying to setup a pipeline in which certain jobs are only running when changes happen in a sub-drectory.

Unfortunately, the effect seems to be that now nothing is starting automatically anymore and the jobs are only run when I trigger the pipeline manually. But my intention is that it still triggers automatrically when changes are pushed.

```yaml
stages:
  - stage-a
  - stage-b

job-a:
  stage: stage-a
  rules:
    - changes:
        paths:
          - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/a/**/*
          - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gitlab-ci.yml
      when: always
  needs: []

job-b:
  stage: stage-b
  rules:
    - changes:
        paths:
          - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/b/**/*
          - $CI_PROJECT_DIR/.gitlab-ci.yml
      when: always
  needs: []
```

I've also tried it without the `when: always` and added different `if` conditions like for example `if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "push"`. But the result is pretty much always the same. The correct job is executed but only when I start the pipeline manually.

Comment: This might have something to do with it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645598/ci-project-dir-not-respected-in-gitlab-ci-rules